# Boost BGL Dijkstra Shortest Paths

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph

I'm not familiar with boost libraries and trying to learn. I have used boost graphics library to call dijstra's shortest paths function to find a path to destination in a map. Vertices are intersections and edges are street segments.

I am finding the shortest path by minimum time. For that I have edge weights defined as time, time = st segment length * its speed/limit. This indeed does give me the shortest path (by time). **However,** I'm to also account for a turn and add 15 seconds to total time for each. How I detect a turn is given two street segments (edges), if the st name of second is not equal to st name of first, it's a turn.

Basically, I want to assign weights dynamically (not just setting them in the beginning like I'm doing here). When the program visits an edge during the search, I'd like it to check the parents (or predecessors here) at this stage. How do I pass in a function or something in the arguments that can do it?

```
vector<unsigned>  OurGraph::find_awesome_path(unsigned start, unsigned finish)
{

    // start and finish are intersection IDs,
    // Get the corresponding Vertices in the graph. 
    Vertex start_node = vertex_map[start]; 
    Vertex dest_node = vertex_map[finish];   

    std::vector<Vertex> predecessors(boost::num_vertices(my_graph)); // To store parents
    std::vector<float> distances(boost::num_vertices(my_graph)); // To store dijkstra distances

    IndexMap indexMap = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, my_graph);
    PredecessorMap predecessorMap(&predecessors[0], indexMap);
    DistanceMap distanceMap(&distances[0], indexMap);

    boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(my_graph, start_node, boost::distance_map(distanceMap).predecessor_map(predecessorMap));
vector<Edge> path;

    path = get_edge_path(dest_node, predecessorMap);    // Extracts edges from edge descriptors in predecessor map
                                                    // and piles them in a vector of Edge. 
    return segment_list_from_edges(path);           // Convert edges to street segment IDs and return.
}
```

Where *my_graph* is a type *Graph* and *Graph , Vertex, Edge, IndexMap, PredecessorMap* and *DistanceMap* are type defined as following:

```
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float> WeightProperty;
typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, unsigned> IntersectionProperty;  
typedef boost::adjacency_list < boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
  IntersectionProperty, WeightProperty > Graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
typedef boost::graph_traits < Graph >::edge_descriptor Edge;
typedef boost::property_map < Graph, boost::vertex_index_t >::type IndexMap;
typedef boost::iterator_property_map < Vertex*, IndexMap, Vertex, Vertex& > PredecessorMap;
typedef boost::iterator_property_map < float*, IndexMap, float, float& > DistanceMap;
```

Comment: You may not be able to use Dijkstra's algorithm for this *directly*, because it assumes that the additional cost incurred by travelling down some edge is independent of how you got to the start vertex.  You can get around this by adding additional edges between every pair of non-adjacent vertices u and v that are on the same street, and then adding 15s to the cost of *every* edge (the new edges will include the 15s cost just once).  Finally, take 15s off whatever solution you get.  Beware: This could be O(n^2) extra edges if all n vertices belong to the same road!

Comment: I did not quite understand the suggestion.
I did the following things (separately each time) in my limited understanding: 
(1) Add extra edges to short-circuit vertices that would be a turn.   
(2) Add extra edges on the vertex that would be on the same street.   
(3) Assigned weights various values instead of 0.25 ....including big and small constant numbers, length of current or next segment, time of current or next segment.   ....They either return illegal path (includes these additional edges), make no difference or return a worse path.

Comment: (2) is closest to being right.  For any pair of vertices u and v **on the same road**, but not right next to each other, you need to add an edge: the purpose of this edge is to allow Dijkstra to pick the corresponding series of edges from the original graph while only paying the 25s turn cost *once*.  So e.g. if you had 5 vertices a, b, c, d, e on the same road, you would add edges ac, bd, ce, ad, be, ae, each with cost equal to the sum of the edges that they "span" +25 (e.g. the cost for be would be the cost(bc)+cost(cd)+cost(de)+25).  All original edges also have their costs increased by 25.

Comment: If Dijkstra includes one of these extra edges in its solution, it means that the underlying set of original edges that it "spans" (e.g. the added edge be spans the original edges bc, cd, and de) are part of the shortest path-that-takes-turns-into-account.

Comment: In the new version of the graph, *every single edge* costs an extra 25s. The idea is that every *turnless subpath* in the original graph corresponds to an edge in the new graph, and the extra 25s is the charge for the turn needed at the start of this subpath.  (Subtract 25 from the final solution because you don't need a turn at the start.)  Although it's possible to make a path like ac->ce in the new graph, which will charge an extra 25s even though it doesn't leave the same road, Dijkstra will never do so, because we ensured that there would already be a cheaper single-edge path, ae.

Comment: Due to time constraints, we're moving on with the flawed version we have now. I'll have to try what you said and get back to you later lol. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to use a differential graph. In that case each vertex in the differential graph would be equivalent to an edge in your current graph. So a vertex would encapsulate a turn for example. Then you can add the turn weights to the edges which involve a change in street name (or whatever mechanism you use to determine turns.)